# MVC3 Locking membership user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I want administrators on my site to be capable of locking members out, but the IsLockedOut() for the default mvc membership is readonly.  I read that I need to create a custom membership provider, but I am not entirely sure what that means.  Do I need to create a new model with a membershipUser property?  If possible, I don't want to create a new table in the database.

Here is the code that I have for my lockUser method:

```
public static void LockUser(this MembershipUser user)
    {
        using (var db = new MovieContext())
        {
            Guid userid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
            MembershipUser member = Membership.GetUser(userid);
            member.IsLockedOut = true;
            member.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: exactly as @SLaks pointed out, the aspnet_Membership table has a booleon fiels called IsLockeOut. Set that to true.

Comment: I tried that - it's readonly.

Comment: not the membership object. The database field.

Comment: How do I access the database directly?

Comment: I saw an example like this: var member = db.aspnet_Membership.Single(m => m.UserId == userid); but my context does not find a definition.

Comment: yes, using linq/EF you can access the row of the user table. If you want to understand linq to entities better, read up on it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have another window up looking at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Andrew, try this approach. It uses IsApproved rather than the IsLockedOut. If your implementation does not already use IsAproved, this would be a good solution.

```
MembershipUser muUser = Membership.GetUser(strUsernameToActOn);
muUser.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(muUser);
```

This is not exactly locking the user. Technically this call is taking approved status from the user and leaving them unable to log-in.

Comment: That works and if it comes down to it I'll use that way, but I would prefer to set the IsLockedOut = true and also set the lockoutdate to the current time.

Comment: @Andrew, for that you would have to go to the db. I've done it. Learn more about EF and implement your own method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it some more.

Comment: After thinking about it, this is better than locking the user out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62707/discussion-between-dave-a-and-zeb).

Comment: Great suggestion, unfortunately I am using the IsAproved member to see if a user account has been approved to be used.